# R latex2exp TeX() greek letter display error

Tags: r, ggplot2, tex

I have a problem with latex2exp TeX() function.
I have no idea why \beta doesn't work here.
As you can see in the figure attached, only blank square appears.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
ggplot(data=B, aes(x=b1)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y=..density..),
    binwidth = .005) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-1.1,1.1)) +
  xlab(TeX(r'(distribution of $\beta_1$)')) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1,color="blue") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -1,color="blue")
```

corresponding plot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `expression`:

```r
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y=..density..),
    binwidth = 1) +
  xlab(expression(distribution~of~beta[1]))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `latex2exp::tex()`, note that backslashes have special meaning to R and need to be *escaped with another backslash*, i.e. you need `'$\\beta_1$`.

Your call to `xlab()` thus could be

```r
xlab(latex2exp::TeX("distribution of $\\beta_1$"))
```